# Nodejs client for SOLR- how to build facets in the query

Tags: node.js, solr, faceted-search

I am trying for some time now to get facets in the nodejs client query that I am using. Below is the snippet for the same.

```
var client = sails.solr;
var query = client.createQuery().q({
  'city_id': options.city_id,
  'content_auto': options.term,
})
.fl('sku+score')
.start(0)
.rows(200)
.facet(true)
.facet.field('brand')
var defer = sails.Q.defer();
client.search(query, function(err, obj){
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error getting data from solr. Error: ' + err);
        return defer.reject(err);
    }
    return defer.resolve(obj.response.docs);
});
return defer.promise;
```

But its not working and there's almost no documentation for the same. Would someone know how to get it working or even a reference would help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked!

```
.facet('brand')
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
.facet(
    {'field':'brand'}
 );
```